# Image gap in Google Mail

Tags: image, html-table, gmail, html-email, newsletter

I seem to be having issues getting an image to line up with another image in a newsletter in Google Mail. I believe it is due to an anchor tag increasing the height of the `<td>` because of its positioning. I have tried to assign a height to the anchor tag, the `<tr>`, and the `<td>` with no luck. Can someone help suggest a solution to this problem. A screenshot of the issue is linked below.

screenshot: http://prntscr.com/2lal9x

Live page with the html code: http://www.birchhavenresort.com/newsletter_templates/general.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some general rules for `table` based `html` email templates:

Add

```
style="display:block"
```

to all **images**.

Don't set the height and width like this,

```
  <td colspan="3" style="padding:0 35px;width:600px;">
```

Instead set it using `height="40"` and `width="300"` for example.

```
  <td width="400" height="40">
```

Also, add `valign="top"` to all `<td>` tags, this will vertically align everything to the top.

Also, some email clients etc will strip out the `padding:0 35px;` bit, so you might need to have some nested tables unfortunately.

Don't style the `<tr>` tags, as this most likely won't work.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I wish tables would die. >_<